# Django ORM - Speed Up Filter w/ M2M

Tags: django, orm

I'm using Django 1.4, Python 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04 and PostgreSQL 9.3.

I have 2 models that are related through a many-to-many (M2M) relationship.  I am getting major performance issues when filtering against the M2M relationship.

```
class Meat(models.Model):
    name1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Potato(models.Model):
    bad_meats = models.ManyToManyField(
        Meat, null=True, blank=True, related_name="bad_potatoes")
```

I'm chaining together filters on the Meat queryset.

```
potato = Potato.objects.get(pk=12345)
qs = Meat.objects.all()
qs = qs.filter(name1='foo')
qs = qs.filter(name2='bar')
qs = qs.exclude(id__in=potato.bad_meats.all())
```

Using the `__in` is slowing down this filtering process significantly.  Is there another approach anyone can suggest that would speed this up?

I cannot use a `.raw()` query because I need to chain filters throughout this process depending on certain conditions.

To give more detail the `Meat` table has about 150,000 rows and the `potato.bad_meats.all()` has about 40,000 results.  This query currently takes about 8-10 seconds.  I need this dropped below 1 second.

Comment: This is fundamentally using a sub query, which is what is causing the slow down.  I can manually do an outer join and speed things up but I don't know how to do that with the Django ORM.

Comment: which database? (this makes difference when performance-tuning)

Comment: I've updated the post to include stack information.

Comment: Try `qs.exclude(bad_potatoes=12345)` instead (I know, doesn't make sense at first but try it and see if it is giving you the expected result).

Comment: @PauloScardine +1 because I learned you can use that syntax to do this.  Unfortunately it seems to take just as long this way.

Comment: Looks like it is time to call the DBA. At a properly configured environment this should not give you any headaches (unless you are evaluating the queryset over a big loop).

Comment: Do you have considered a `.row` query?

Comment: How about:
`qs = Meat.objects.prefetch_related('bad_potatoes').filter(name1='foo',name2='bar').exclude(bad_potatoes__id=12345).all()`

Comment: Do you have django_debug_toolbar on by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

150K rows and 40K relations does not seem to be so big it takes 8s, maybe your machine has a low cpu ?

Here are some stuffs you can check/try:

- Did you check there are index and foreignkeys for the concerned columns in your db structure ?
- Did you try adding index on name1 and name2 columns ?
- You should also try to monitor the time taken in python code to do the mapping between the raw result and the Model, it can be more significant than the query time. You may try using `values` or `values_list` to get dict/list instead of Model objects.

Regarding the db query I found a slightly faster query (but on my machine this is not significant).
I created a db with 150K meats and 1 potato linked to 40K meats. Using the same approach as yours run in less than 1s on my machine with 2.3Gz.

I printed the generated query like this

```
>>> qs = Meat.objects.filter(name1='foo').filter(name2='bar').exclude(id__in=potato.bad_meats.all())
>>> print qs.query
SELECT "coucou_meat"."id", "coucou_meat"."name1", "coucou_meat"."name2" 
FROM "coucou_meat" 
WHERE ("coucou_meat"."name1" = foo  AND "coucou_meat"."name2" = bar 
AND NOT ("coucou_meat"."id" IN
    (SELECT U0."id" 
    FROM "coucou_meat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "coucou_potato_bad_meats" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."meat_id") 
    WHERE U1."potato_id" = 1 )))
```

I tried to run it directly in pgadmin, the query took 325ms.

Then I tried a slightly different query :

```
>>> qs = Meat.objects.filter(name1='foo').filter(name2='bar').exclude(bad_potatoes__id=12345)
>>> print qs.query
SELECT "coucou_meat"."id", "coucou_meat"."name1", "coucou_meat"."name2" 
FROM "coucou_meat" WHERE ("coucou_meat"."name1" = foo  AND "coucou_meat"."name2" = bar  
AND NOT (("coucou_meat"."id" IN 
    (SELECT U1."meat_id" 
    FROM "coucou_potato_bad_meats" U1 
    WHERE (U1."potato_id" = 1  AND U1."meat_id" IS NOT NULL)) 
        AND "coucou_meat"."id" IS NOT NULL)))
```

Run it in pgadmin and got 230ms execution time. Since it is a bit faster you may try it to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: To add indexes between Meat and Potatoes should I just declare `index=True` on the M2M definition?

Comment: Django put index on ForeignKeys and m2m by default, if you generated db with django there is no raison they are missing. But it worth checking because performances would be horrible without these index.